# How to show multiple value columns in aggregate function in R

Tags: r

I have the data set below:

```
TableA = data.frame(Product = c('iPhone', 'Macbook', 'Airpod', 'Macbook', 'Airpod', 'Macbook', 'iPhone'), East = c(1:7), West = c(5:11), North = c(15:21), South = c(24:30))
```

And I want to group all the 4 region columns without mentioning the region name using cbind() function (because my real world dataset has 72 value columns which keeps changing).

The below for one region works fine:

```
aggregate(East ~ Product, TableA, sum)
```

The below for all the regions also works fine (but region names are mentioned):

```
aggregate(cbind(East, West, North, South) ~ Product, TableA, sum)
```

But this one doesn't work where I tried to take the region names from the data frame directly:

```
aggregate(cbind(TableA[0,1]) ~ Product, TableA, sum)
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Just use `aggregate(. ~ Product, TableA, sum)` ?

Comment: There are possibilities with `dplyr` as well in case you're willing to change your approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternativ to  `aggregate()` (solution provided by Taufi). Here is a `dplyr` solution where you can calculate the sum of all numeric columns:

```
library(dplyr)
TableA %>% 
  group_by(Product) %>% 
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), ~sum(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Output:

```
  Product  East  West North South
  <chr>   <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 Airpod      8    16    36    54
2 iPhone      8    16    36    54
3 Macbook    12    24    54    81
```

Comment: One more question. It would be great if you can clarify.
Can we filter the data before aggregation?

Comment: Yes! This should not encounter the `summarise` process. For example: `filter(Product == 'Macbook')`

Comment: I couldn't understand. But I used like the below. 

library(dplyr)
TableA[TableA$A == "Condition 1" & TableA$B == "Condition 2", ] %>% 

Multiple filters because my real world data set has more text columns.

Thank you TarJae !!!

Comment: `library(dplyr)`  TableA %>% filter(A == "Condition1" & B == "Condition2")